# DataBricks - Ingest new data from parquet files into delta / delta lake table

Tags: databricks, parquet, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I posted [this question on the databricks forum](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/57978/if-i-create-a-delta-table-using-a-select-from-a-so.html), I'll copy below but basically I need to ingest new data from parquet files into a delta table. I think I have to figure out how to use a merge statement effectively and / or use an ingestion tool.

I'm mounting some parquet files and then I create a table like this:

```
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE myTableName USING parquet LOCATION 'myMountPointLocation'");
```

And then I create a delta table with a subset of columns and also a subset of the records. If I do both these things, my queries are super fast.

```
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE $myDeltaTableName USING DELTA SELECT A, B, C FROM myTableName WHERE Created > '2021-01-01'");
```

What happens if I now run:

```
sqlContext.sql("REFRESH TABLE myTableName");
```

Does my table now update with any additional data that may be present in my parquet source files? Or do I have to re-mount those parquet files to get additional data?

Does my delta table also update with new records? I doubt it but one can hope...

Is this a case for AutoLoader? Or maybe I do some combination of mounting, re-creating / refreshing my source table, and then maybe MERGE new records / updated records into my delta table?